# Strange behaviour with detecting specific puntucations in regex

Tags: java, regex, encoding

The following code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          // Create a Pattern object
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[?:!.,;'’\"“”«»<>=()_-]+");

          // Now create matcher object.
          Matcher m = r.matcher("Hello,World!");

          while(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group());

         }
}
```

outputs:

```
,
!
```

If I add the punctuation – in the regex (longer hyphen) so that it becomes:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[?:!.,;'’\"“”«»<>=()_-–]+");
```

the output becomes:

```
ello, 
orld!
```

is anybody able to tell me why this strange malfunction?

Comment: Because this way the `-` character acts as range from `_` to long hyphen

Comment: `Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[?:!.,;'’\"“”«»<>=()_–-]+");` Make sure to keep `-` at first or last position in character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the dash (`-`) between `_` and `–` which creates a range, and includes all characters whose Unicode codepoints are between `_` and `–`.

- `_` is U+005F
- `–` is U+2013

So everything in-between is included in the range. This includes the lowercase Latin characters (these range from U+0061 to U+007A).

Uppercase Latin characters range from U+0041 to U+005A and are therefore located *before* the underscore at U+005F. These get excluded from the character class.

Put the dash at the start or the end of the character class to fix the issue.

```
[?:!.,;'’\"“”«»<>=()_–-]+
```

Alternatively, you could escape it with a backslash, but I'd advise you to stick with the first/last rule as it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Some Class basics:

All regex special characters can be escaped outside of classes so
its *literal* meaning is invoked.

Inside classes, on first glance, the ascii dash symbol `-` is a *range* operator,
which you recall.

To invoke its literal meaning, it can be placed at the beginning or end of the
class.

But, regex parsing is much more simplistic than you might imagine.
It really doesn't matter where the dash is placed inside a class.

Parsing single characters from left to right, a single character represents
the left position. If a dash is the next character found, the next single
character represents the right position. This constitutes a simple *range*
construct inside classes.

Anything outside that construct, the dash is a literal.

For example `[a-c-m-o]` represent a,b,c,m,n,o, and -

So, a dash at the beginning or end cannot be *parsed* as a range operator,
neither if it's between ranges or to the right of one ( example: `[a-d-tovz]` ).
Of course at the beginning or end its easier
to be assured its not being used as a range operator.

As always, anything escaped in a class is treated as a literal, property, or
control code.

Also, properties can't be the left/right side of a range construct.

Java has some others special class constructs, such as unions operators and
nested classes, but I think the range operator functionality is mostly
the same for all engines.